# Connecting to an external SQL Database using odbc commands and C#

Tags: c#, sql, odbc

I am trying to write C# code to access a database using odbc commands, the database is not local.

My connection string looks like that:

```
Driver={SQL Server};Server=serverName;Database=dbname;UID=username;PWD=apassword;
```

Somehow I cannot get the connection to open....

Can someone explain why? am i missing something in the string?

Comment: It looks okay to me, if you're happy to use the old SQL Server driver. Can you post the error message?

Comment: turns out I was only missing the instance of the server

Answer (score 0):

Try this ODBC connection string:

> Driver={SQL Native Client};Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;
>   Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;

as described [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005)